# Oracle versions supported by WSO2 Registry 4.5.3?

Tags: oracle, wso2

What oracle versions are supported by wso2 registry 4.5.3 ?

Regards

Comment: That's something you should look up on WSO2's website, and contact their support team if the information isn't readily available.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Greg does support oracle but it has not been tested again every version but should work with any version. check out the documentation on oracle [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Setting+up+with+Oracle)